# Reading a default Environment Variable from LaunchSettings.json in ASP.NET Core 7 Application

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I working on an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API project. I want to read the system environment variables and I want to the application so if the system environment variable is not defined, it should pick the default value from the `launchSettings.json` file.

When I am reading the environment variable value using

```
var hostUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOST_URL");
```

I am getting null.

Here is my `launchSettings.json` file:

```
"profiles": {
    "http": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": false,
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5265",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
            "HOST_URL": "http://localhost:8081"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `launchSettings.json` file:

1. Is only used on the local development machine.
2. Is not deployed.
3. Contains profile settings.

Source from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson).

So is not used to use the environment variables. You should define them in the `appsettings.json`.

Comment: How can I make it optional ?
I mean if the environment variables are defined on system then pick the value from there other pick the value from appsettings.json

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused why you wanna configure `environment variables` in `launchSettings.json`? If you wanna set `environment variables`, You can right click on your project, then click `Properties`, this will open properties page. Click on Debug tab and `Open debug launch profiles UI` you will see Environment Variables as shown below.

[image]

You can change the value as per your need. This value will be saved in the `launchSettings.json`. In your code, you can use

```
var result = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")
```

to read the environment variables

[image]